# CSS text-decoration: reverse

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I'm surprised that there is no "text-decoration: reverse" in CSS as it seems very awkward to achieve using JavaScript. I.E. set the element's foreground and background color to the background and foreground of the parent respectively.

I noticed JavaScript techniques for that [here](http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2006/07/retrieving-css-styles-via-javascript/)

Surely it's not that complicated?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but a better name for this might be "invert" rather than "reverse."

Comment: It's called "reverse video" from the days of terminals and curses.  Agree it's confusing in that you might expect the characters themselves to be reversed.

Answer (score 5):

What are you calling reverted?
Do you mean to set the background as the foreground color and vice versa?
(Maybe it's a stupid comment, but if so it is not a decoration is it?)

Anyway you're about to have a fight between DRY and MVC here :

- either you declare a new CSS class
  each time you want to do that. That's
  redundant and painful, but you indeed
  separated the style from the code.

Typically:

```
.mydiv {
   background-color: blue;
   color: red;
   font-family:...;
   (...)
}


.mydiv:hover {
   color: red;
   background-color: blue;
}
```

- another option is to do that through javascript. Proxify suggested using jQuery.

  The result would probably look like that... (not tested)

```
$(".invert").map(function (el) {
       var color = el.css("color");
       var bgcolor = el.css("background-color");
       el.css("color", bgcolor).css("background-color",color);
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The concept of "reversing" background and foreground style of text is not that easy to implement to the browser. If one allow your "text-decoration: reverse" in the browser, should background image also reverse onto texts? This is not what a browser today can draw.

Now consider transparencies and those alpha value. There are many aspects that make your idea of "reverse" impractical to implement in general.

Comment: A fair point. I'm just considering nested <span> tags on text, and so swapping the foreground and background colors is fine there.

Answer (score 0):

well you could try using jQuery, it's a simpler way to achieve the same as normal javascript.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
var bgColor = "#123456";
var textColor = bgColor.match(/^#([0-8][0-9a-fA-F])+$/g) == null ? "#000000" : "#ffffff";
```

So it uses white colored text for dark bacground colors, and black text color for lighter background colors.

Answer (score -1):

While there is no CSS available to reverse text, there does exist a html element called bdo (bi-directional override) and the selector dir="rtl" and with it you can reverse text.

You can reverse the text in your page

If you then give it a class, you can then add additional style elements, for example, and you'll need to view the source code for this page to "read" what I've done. (p.s. you don't need to include the  element, that's there to differentiate the code from the rest of this blurb...)

`You can reverse the text in your page`

`.reverso
{   color: #cc3300; 
    font-size: 200%; }`

and so on.

I hope that helps (O:

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this - 
http://www.priteshgupta.com/2011/09/flip-or-reverse-text-using-css/