# How do I make text reverse direction in HTML?

Tags: css

I am working on a creative website featuring silly limericks. I would like to display each line of the limerick in an alternating direction. That is, I want it in [boustophedon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon). I was wondering if this was possible with just HTML.

As an example, I would like to be able to write markup that looks something like this:

```
<p>
  <forward>There once was a young lady with pride,<br>
  <backward>who ate fourteen green apples and died.<br>
  <forward>Within the lamented,<br>
  <backward>the apple fermented<br>
  <forward>and made cider inside her insides.
</p>
```

which would display something like this

> There once was a young lady with pride,
>   .deid dna selppa neerg neetruof eta ohw
>   Within the lamented,
>   detnemref elppa eht
>   and made cider inside her insides.

For this example, I just manually wrote the text backwards, but I don't want to have to keep doing that since it's a very tedious process. It would be nice if I could do this in pure HTML, without having to do any scripting to dynamically manipulate the text.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406368/can-you-use-css-to-mirror-flip-text

Comment: And some inspiration here: http://yichuanshen.de/blog/2011/01/08/reflecting-text-with-pure-css3/

Comment: Also related: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660634/css-text-decoration-reverse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660634/css-text-decoration-reverse)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the combination of two Unicode control characters. Namely, the

- 'RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE' (U+202E)
- 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE' (U+202D)

Each override character makes the text that follows it flow in the corresponding direction.

These can be inserted into an document with the HTML entities `&#x202E;` and `&#x202D;`, or the decimal equivalents, `&#8238;` and `&#8237;`.

This allows you to write your example thus:

```
<p>
  There once was a young lady with pride,<br>
  &#x202e;who ate fourteen green apples and died.<br>
  &#x202d;Within the lamented,<br>
  &#x202e;the apple fermented<br>
  &#x202d;and made cider inside her insides.
</p>
```

I'm posting this HTML in now so you can see how it appears. You can observe the actual direction change by selecting parts of the text.

> There once was a young lady with pride,
>     ‮who ate fourteen green 123 apples and died.
>     ‭Within the lamented,
>     ‮the apple fermented
>     ‭and made cider inside her insides.

If you wanted a *true* boustrephedon, where the letters forms are also backwards, and if you don't mind using CSS3 features, then you could use a CSS3 transform:

```css
backward {
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

```html
<p>
  There once was a lady with pride,<br>
  <backward>who ate fourteen green apples and died.</backward><br> Within the lamented,<br>
  <backward>the apple fermented</backward><br> and made cider inside her insides.
</p>
```

Comment: +1 How can I use CSS3 transforms in Stack posts? If it's possible could you provide an example in your answer?

Comment: @draks... I don't think it's possible, unfortunately

Comment: Sad, I've seen usernames with reverted chararcters. How does this work?

Comment: @draks... They use the unicode character `&#x202e;` (U+202E).

Comment: &#x202e; but this doesn't revert the single chararcters...(and doesn't work in coments ;-)

Comment: @PeterOlson, So isn't this character usable for injection attacks? Just add it into an input box and the rest of the characters end up mirrored.

Comment: @Pacerier Yes there are some potential attacks for using this character, for example sending an EXE file to somebody (say `evilcod.exe`) and disguising it as a DOC file (`evilexe.doc`).

Comment: @draks...: "reverse", not "revert" (yes, very closely related words).

Comment: ‮ !̱͈͓͘ͅr̮̙̱̰̪̖͚e̷w͓̟ś͓̹̤̠̲̤n̲͓̮̗͔͈͙͏a̡͓̹̙͔̣̰̩ ̙̗̻͖̘̻̫t͍͈a̡͈e̱̮̪̤͓͙͖r͙͉̼̩ͅG

Comment: @draks... Doesn't work in comments you say? ‮ ?teb annaW

Comment: I would also like to note that with the Unicode control characters, the `span` and `b`, etc doesn't stop the direction change.

Answer (score 25):

Try this.

```css
span {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

```html
<span>who ate fourteen green apples and died.</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[bdo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdo)** tag like so:

```css
bdo[dir='rtl'] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
There once was a lady with pride,<br>
<bdo dir='rtl'>who ate fourteen green apples and died.</bdo><br> 
Within the lamented,<br>
<bdo dir='rtl'>the apple fermented</bdo><br> 
and made cider inside her insides.
```