# Flipped punctuation in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm getting the following (Notice the quotation marks and "..." on the wrong side) :

[image]

What I want is `"This is a very very very long comment..."`

This is the HTML Code (I'm using `angularjs` but it doesn't work even without it):

```
<span class="comment ng-binding">"This is a very very very long comment..."</span>
```

This is the css for `comment`:

```
ul#comment-list .comment-comment .comment {
   color:#000;
   display:block;
   text-align:left
}
```

I've checked all the settings in Chrome developer tools to make sure some stray css rule isn't messing everything up, but there's nothing wrong there, no matter what css rule I disable.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing what ng-binding does in CSS or javascript. I think it may be adding the quote marks for you - if so, your quote marks in the span will mess it up. Try with no quote marks in the span and see what happens.

Comment: It seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/nd9Tj/

Comment: I [can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/m2ej6/), something must be missing from your test case.

Comment: @DeborahSpeece Sorry, I should have mentioned for those unfamiliar. `ng-binding` is just a class `angularjs` uses to keep track of elements. It has no css rules.

Comment: [Are you hiding `direction:rtl;` from us?](http://jsfiddle.net/m2ej6/1/) Inspect the rules on that element to see if that gets applied.

Comment: @trojansdestroy ...oh. Thanks so much! I completely forgot that I had that on my `ul` in order to get the scroll bar on the right side. I didn't know that it also changed punctuation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have `direction:rtl;` applied to your comment element. As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction), with `direction`:

> ltr: The initial value of direction (that is, if not otherwise specified). Text and other elements go from left to right.
>
> rtl: Text and other elements go from right to left

Why, then, is the text not backwards, letter-for-letter?

<del>For the direction property to have any effect on inline-level elements, the [`unicode-bidi`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unicode-bidi) property's value must be `embed` or `override`.</del> (seems not to be true in testing)

You must use a Unicode control character, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180034/2231440). And [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m2ej6/2/); note that only the punctuation is flipped on the second output line, but everything is flipped on the third line (with the control character).

Answer (score -3):

The quotation symbol (i.e. ") is reserved in HTML.  Replace it with

```
&quot;
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using double quotes try using `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;` for left and right double quotes. Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp).